# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Slot

Tags: python

I am trying to access values of a list containing instances of a Class

## This is how I store the elements in a list

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(self, slot, available):
        self.slot = slot
        self.available = available

for i in range(rangeHours):
    timeSlots.append(i)
    timeSlots[i] = Slot(hours[i],free[i])
```

## This is the code that gives me an error

```
for call in calls:
    if call == 1:
        for i in timeSlots:
            if timeSlots[i].available == True:
                patient[i] = Patient(timeSlots[i].slot)
                timeSlots[i].available == False
```

## Error code:

if timeSlots[i].available == True:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Slot

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a *dict* instead of a *list*. You can also use a *list* for the same purpose, but not the way you structured your code. Why? Let's see in detail what you are doing:

```py
# Lets say you have an empty list:

time_slots = []
```

You loop through integers and append them into your list:

```py
for i in range(rangeHours):
    time_slots.append(i)
```

After the first iteration, you list will be:

```py
# time_slots = [0]
```

Then you are accessing the same element you have just appended using it as index:

```py
# time_slots[0] = 0 , which in this case, the element you accessed is 0
```

Then you change this element to be your *Slot* class:

```py
# time_slots[0] = Slot(hours[0],free[0])
```

Which directly overwrites what you have just put into your list. In short, time_slots.append(i) has no effect.

I think you should use a *dict* instead:

```py
time_slots = {}
for i in range(rangeHours):
    time_slots[i] = Slot(hours[i],free[i])
```

Then you can do:

```py
for call in calls:
    if call == 1:
        for slot_index, slot_class in time_slots.items():
            if slot_class.available == True:
                patient[slot_index] = Patient(slot_class.slot)
                slot_class.available == False
```

Comment: Thank you Kivanc!